# My date is always one hour out - Parsing a JSON date

Tags: javascript, datetime

I live in GMT and it's +1 daylight savings at the moment, which is probably relevant...

I have a webservice, and it pulls down a date which ends up in this format

'\/Date(1234567)\/'

In order to find out what this date is, I simply Eval it after removing the slashes.

Here's an example:

```
var jsonDate = 'Date(1304515498497)';

alert (new Date(1304515498497).toString() + "\n" +
           Date(1304515498497).toString()  + "\n" +
            eval(jsonDate));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yPCNE/1/

If I put new in front of it, the date changes, and it is incorrect. However, in my code, if I remove New, I always get today's date. This may be a consequence of using the datejs library. From what I can see, doing eval('new ' + date) is resulting in the time being exactly one hour behind, but alert()ing both of the dates shows they are both set to +1 GMT and are identical except for the one hour. I can't fathom where it's coming from.

Is there some better way to do this? I just want to convert the incoming JSON date into a regular date without any +1s messing it up.

Comment: JSON doesn't refer to JavaScript's syntax in general, but to a standardized subset of it (see [json.org](http://json.org/)). I don't believe this question is actually JSON-related.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't put `new` in front of it, `Date().toString()` will just return the current time, whatever you put inside the brackets.

```
alert (Date(1).toString() + "\n" +
       Date(42).toString()  + "\n" +
       Date("banana").toString());  //All return current time
```